# adding directory to my servlet web-app web.xml

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web.xml

Basically I have servlet web-app and I have a directory out the my web-app project say `D:\resources`, here in my porject web.xml I need to specify that the resources that my web-app would need could be found at `D:\resources`, I would really appreciate if you tell me how to specify a directory to my project web.xml file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Best way of achieving this is to configre your external resources with defining  JNDI in your application server and then referring the same in your web.xml like for e.g.

```
<resource-description>
   <res-ref-name>myAppResources</res-ref-name>
   <jndi-name>myResource</jndi-name>
</resource-description>
```